# VisualStudio: Determine which syntax color rule has been applied

Tags: visual-studio-2017, syntax-highlighting

I'm using Visual studio 2017 on a C++ project and have a header file with a triple slash comment (/// Foo). This is coloured differently to double slash comments (// Bar) and in my current scheme is hard to read. I realise that I don't know how to change that colour though as I don't know which formatting rule has been applied (and there are so many rules these days that it's impractical to look at all of them).

Is there any way to determine which rule applies to a certain text selection? Failing that, if anyone knows which rule applies to /// that would be a start. But a general solution would be ideal.

Thanks,
-Dave

Answer (score -1):

The rules for the triple slash is XML Doc Comment.

Comment: Here I was hoping for a general answer..